# how to make images appear on top of one another automatically

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to do this for a while but i have not been able to find anything on the internet. What i am trying to do is have a bunch of images and have one displayed at a time. So image 1 fades in for 2 seconds and fades out, image 2 does the same, then image 3 etc. i am trying to pull this off with css, I don't want to start jumping into js if not needed. The code i have here works great, but with one caveat: it runs only once. If i add animation-iteration-count:infinite, all the images will start blinking at the same time! can't seem to figure it out.

```css
@keyframes bruh {

    0% {opacity: 1;}
    75% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}

}
 
.a1{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: bruh;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    
    }
.a2{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: bruh;
  
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    }
.a3{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: bruh;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    }
.a4{
    position: relative;
    
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: bruh;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    }
```

```html
<img src="IMG_4591.JPG" class = "a1">
   <img src="IMG_4594.JPG" class = "a2">
   <img src="seadoo icon.jpg" class = "a3">
   <img src="renken 1950.jpg" class = "a4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the delay that only runs once.
You need a function that takes the whole loop into account, in this case the full 8 seconds. I have adjusted the percentages roughly to go with your example. ( 0-75-100 ).

```
 @keyframes pert {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  19% { opacity: 1; }
  25% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
 }

 [class^="a"] {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: pert;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }

.a1 { animation-delay: 0s; }
.a2 { animation-delay: 2s; }
.a3 { animation-delay: 4s; }
.a4 { animation-delay: 6s; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it well without JavaScript. Keep in mind that the timing depends on the number of images. The more images, the longer each image needs to wait for its next turn.